# Viewport Overlay Bug

Tags: cloth-simulation

Working with **Cloth** in **Sculpting** and **Sculpt Mode** I was not able to get **Faceset** selection coloring to display.
I fixed the issue by messing around in **Viewport Overlays**; ticking a bunch of boxes, exiting, entering and ticking them all off again.

Nothing relevant was or was not ticked initially - it just seems like Viewport Overlay needed to be 'tickled' to respond.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file before you fixed the issue? What option did you ticked exactly to display the facesets?

Comment: That file is long gone now. Sorry.

Comment: I would suggest ticking all on and all off.

Comment: This is similar to another issue in Blender where sometimes you can not advance through or see folders in the file list; you have to toggle stuff until Blender snaps out of it or reset.